# How to get rid unused storage?

Tags: storage, runtime-upgrade

Let's say we get rid of a pallet after a runtime upgrade. My question is do the storage keys related to the now removed pallet just get pruned away automatically or is there some kind of manual intervention required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The runtime does not detect unused storage. It needs to be removed manually.
There is a `RemovePallet` migration that can be used, but it needs careful consideration on a parachain to not overflow the weight.

A more general way it to write a multi-block migration, for example in an `on_idle` hook and cleanup the elements one by one.